# How can I write a function that is iterable?

Tags: r, string, function, dataframe, dplyr

I need to modify a function (below) that will apply row-wise with `dplyr::mutate` to remove any '_' characters and capitalise the first letter of each word.

My function

```
simple_cap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
        sep="", collapse=" ")
}
```

My data

```
df <- read.table(text = c('
location             obs

1 australia         12454.
2 new_south_wales    3931.
3 victoria           3244.
4 queensland         2477.
5 south_australia     834.
6 western_australia  1335.
7 tasmania            246.'), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The `dplyr::mutate` call:

```
df %>% mutate(
  location = simple_cap(location)
)
```

The output

```
location   obs
1 Australia 12454
2 Australia  3931
3 Australia  3244
4 Australia  2477
5 Australia   834
6 Australia  1335
7 Australia   246
```

How can I change my function so that it can be used to iterate over the values in `df$location` rather than replacing them all with the output from the first element?

Comment: Ronak Shah and akrun have provided you with options that work for your specific problem case. Take a look at my answer re: how you do this in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)  With gsub**

We can use `gsub` to select the lower case characters (`[a-z]`), capture as a group (`(...)`) that is the first letter of the string (`^`) or (`|`) that follows an underscore (`_`) and replace with the backreference after converting to upper case (`\\U`)

Wrap with another `gsub` to remove the `_` and replace with `" "`

```
df %>%
  mutate(location = gsub("_", " ", gsub("(^|_)([a-z])", "\\1\\U\\2", location, perl = TRUE)))
#           location   obs
#1         Australia 12454
#2   New South Wales  3931
#3          Victoria  3244
#4        Queensland  2477
#5   South Australia   834
#6 Western Australia  1335
#7          Tasmania   246
```

---

**2) With stringi**

Or another option is `stri_trans_totitle` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
df %>%
  mutate(location = stri_trans_totitle(stri_replace_all_fixed(location, "_", " ")))
#          location   obs
#1         Australia 12454
#2   New South Wales  3931
#3          Victoria  3244
#4        Queensland  2477
#5   South Australia   834
#6 Western Australia  1335
#7          Tasmania   246
```

**3) Using OP's modified function**

The `strsplit` output is a `list`.  In the OP's code, it is just subsetting the first element by extracting `[[1]]`.  But, here we have a `list` of length 7.  So, one option is to use `map` from `purrr` (or with `lapply/sapply` from `base R`) and then do the `paste`ing of the `substring`

```
simple_cap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, "_")
  purrr::map_chr(s,  ~
    paste(toupper(substring(.x, 1,1)), substring(.x, 2),
         sep="", collapse=" "))
 }

df %>%
     mutate(location = simple_cap(location))
#           location   obs
#1         Australia 12454
#2   New South Wales  3931
#3          Victoria  3244
#4        Queensland  2477
#5   South Australia   834
#6 Western Australia  1335
#7          Tasmania   246
```

**4) OP's modified function with sapply**

```
simple_cap <- function(x) {
   s <- strsplit(x, "_")
    sapply(s,  function(.s)
    paste(toupper(substring(.s, 1,1)), substring(.s, 2),
       sep="", collapse=" "))
 }
```

**5) No external packages**

But, this can be done without using any external package

```
df$location <- gsub("_", " ", gsub("(^|_)([a-z])", "\\1\\U\\2", df$location, perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: That seems to capitalise the first letter of each word but not remove the '_' characters?

Comment: This is a good answer, because it shows @Dom why his function isn't vectorized, and gives an option that uses a similar approach but is vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `str_to_title` function in `stringr` which capitalises the first character of word and with `gsub` we replace all the "_" (underscore) with "  " (blank space).

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(location = str_to_title(gsub("_", " ", location)))


#           location   obs
#1         Australia 12454
#2   New South Wales  3931
#3          Victoria  3244
#4        Queensland  2477
#5   South Australia   834
#6 Western Australia  1335
#7          Tasmania   246
```

Answer (score 2):

Ronak Shah and akrun have solved your specific problem. Here's the general solution to your title question (how do I write a function that is iterable).

In the parlance of R, you want a vectorized function -- a function that accepts a vector input and returns a vector output. There are two ways to do this.

1) Make sure each step in your function can accept a vector input and return a vector output. @akrun's 4th answer identifies the step in your code that prevents it from doing this, `s <- strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]`.

2) Turn a non-vectorized function into a vectorized one with `Vectorize`. **Option 1 is more efficient, but sometimes it's not possible.**  This is clearly an example where it's possible, but to show you how this works, lets vectorize your function with `Vectorize`

```
simple_cap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, "_")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
        sep="", collapse=" ")
}

simple_cap_v <- Vectorize(simple_cap, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
simple_cap(df$location)
# [1] "Australia"
simple_cap_v(df$location)
# [1] "Australia"         "New South Wales"   "Victoria"          "Queensland"       
# [5] "South Australia"   "Western Australia" "Tasmania"  

df %>% mutate(
  location = simple_cap_v(location)
)
#            location   obs
# 1         Australia 12454
# 2   New South Wales  3931
# 3          Victoria  3244
# 4        Queensland  2477
# 5   South Australia   834
# 6 Western Australia  1335
# 7          Tasmania   246
```

`Vectorize` returns a function that is a wrapper to `mapply`. Effectively, a call to `simple_cap_v(x)` is now `mapply(simple_cap, x, USE.NAMES = FALSE)`

Comment: @akrun `Vectorize` uses `lapply`, but object returned is a function that is a wrapper to `mapply`. See the source code: `FUNV <- function()... do.call("mapply", c(FUN = FUN, args[dovec], MoreArgs = list(args[!dovec])`. The object `Vectorize` returns is `FUNV`

Comment: @akrun It exactly won't improve efficiency. That's why, if you can write it your way, you do. (And that's why I upvoted your answer and bolded that part of my answer).